# Flash file Link

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a flash file menu i am having problem while link it to my other web pages the code is below.

```
<div id="flashcontent">
<a href="http://www.Yahoo.com.com">Home</a>|
<a href="http://www.gmail.com">Products</a>|
<a href="Home.htm">Downloads</a>|
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("10.swf","10","170","415","8","#3D596C"); 
so.addParam("allowScriptAccess","always"); so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

The first two link are working as you can see i have link with http but the third link which i link to my directory page is not working. someone please help me out how i write this for my local directory page.
Thanks

Comment: How this question is related to the Flash object? You are only talking about a pure HTML link item. Misleading subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that this file is at a deeper directory say `/mydirectory/page` and the Downloads link is at `/Home.htm`.  Here is a great resource.

http://www.compugoddess.com/relvsabs.htm

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a href="/Home.htm">Downloads</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure you got the filename correctly?
It may be ".html" instead of ".htm", and your system may be case-sensitive with filenames.

Comment: No when i preview it on Frontpage it is working fine with this code <a href="../10/sample.html">Downloads</a> but when i run it on browser its not working.